How to manage nested twoPane layout in compose
I have an app which has four screens:

HomeScreen
SavedScreen
RecommendationScreen
DetailsScreen

I am unssure how to manage the navigation with a permanent navigation drawer and how to implement a twopane composable like this:

I found a similar problem here: How to implement nested navigation in a Two Pane layout in Jetpack Compose?
But I find it quite tricky because of the navigation drawer.
@Composable
fun PragueApp(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    widthClass: WindowWidthSizeClass,
    viewModel: PragueViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    val backSTackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = CurrentPage.valueOf(
        backSTackEntry?.destination?.route ?: CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN.name
    )
    val navigationType = when (widthClass) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> NavigationType.BOTTOMBAR
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> NavigationType.RAIL
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> NavigationType.DRAWER
        else -> NavigationType.BOTTOMBAR
    }

    if (navigationType == NavigationType.DRAWER) {
        PermanentNavigationDrawer(
            drawerContent = {
                PermanentDrawerSheet {
                    NavigationHeader()
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.home)) },
                        selected = currentScreen == CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN,
                        onClick = { navController.navigate(CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN.name) },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = if (currentScreen == CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN) Icons.Filled.Home else Icons.Outlined.Home,
                                contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.home),
                            )
                        }
                    )
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        selected = currentScreen == CurrentPage.SAVEDSCREEN,
                        onClick = { navController.navigate(CurrentPage.SAVEDSCREEN.name) },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painter = if (currentScreen == CurrentPage.SAVEDSCREEN) painterResource(
                                    id = R.drawable.baseline_bookmark_24
                                ) else painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_bookmark_border_24),
                                contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.saved),
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.saved)) },
                    )
                }
            }
        ) {
            TwoPaneContent()
        } else {
            SinglePaneContent(//)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TwoPaneContent() {
}

@Composable
fun SinglePaneContent(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    navigationType: NavigationType,
) {
    val viewModel: PragueViewModel = viewModel()
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val backstack by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = CurrentPage.valueOf(
        backstack?.destination?.route ?: CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN.name
    )
    viewModel.isSinglePane(true)
    val content = remember {
        movableContentOf<PaddingValues> { innerPadding ->
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN.name,
            ) {
                composable(CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN.name) {
                    CityHomeScreenList(
                        categoriesList = LocalHomePageCategoriesProvider.allCategories,
                        isDeviceNotExpanded = true,
                        onCategoryClick = {
                            viewModel.navigateToRecommendationScreen(it)
                            navController.navigate(CurrentPage.RECOMMENDATIONSSCREEN.name)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                    )
                }
                composable(CurrentPage.SAVEDSCREEN.name) {
                    SavedScreen(
                        savedRecommendationsMap = uiState.SavedRecommendationScreenList,
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.navigateToDetailScreen(it)
                            navController.navigate(CurrentPage.DETAILSSCREEN.name)
                        },
                        onFilterButtonClick = { category, isSelected ->
                            viewModel.SavedScreenFilter(category, isSelected)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                    )
                }
                composable(CurrentPage.RECOMMENDATIONSSCREEN.name) {
                    RecommendationScreenList(
                        recommendationList = uiState.currentRecommendationScreen!!.second,
                        onClick = { viewModel.navigateToDetailScreen(it) },
                    )
                }
                composable(CurrentPage.DETAILSSCREEN.name) {
                    DetailsScreen(
                        recommendation = uiState.currentDetailsScreen!!.first,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                    )
                }
            }
        }

    }
    RailorBottommBarLayout(
        onArrowClick = { navController.navigateUp() },
        onSavedClick = { navController.navigate(CurrentPage.SAVEDSCREEN.name) },
        onHomeClick = { navController.navigate(CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN.name) },
        onSaveItemClick = { viewModel.SaveUnSaveRecommendation(it) },
        navigationType = navigationType,
    ) { innerPadding ->
        content(innerPadding)
    }
}

@Composable
fun RailorBottommBarLayout(
    currentScreen: CurrentPage = CurrentPage.HOMESCREEN,
    onArrowClick: () -> Unit,
    onSaveItemClick: (isSaved: Boolean) -> Unit,
    onHomeClick: () -> Unit,
    onSavedClick: () -> Unit,
    isSaved: Boolean? = null,
    navigationType: NavigationType,
    content: @Composable (innerPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit,
) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        if (navigationType == NavigationType.RAIL) {
            PragueNavigationRail(
                currentPage = currentScreen,
                onHomeClick = onHomeClick,
                onSavedClick = onSavedClick,
            )
        }
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                PragueTopAppBar(
                    isSaved = isSaved,
                    onSaveItemClick = onSaveItemClick,
                    currentScreen = currentScreen,
                    onArrowClick = onArrowClick,
                )
            },
            bottomBar = {
                AnimatedVisibility(navigationType == NavigationType.BOTTOMBAR) {
                    PragueAppBottomBar(
                        currentPage = currentScreen,
                        onHomeClick = onHomeClick,
                        onSavedClick = onSavedClick,
                    )
                }
            }
        ) {
            content(it)
        }
    }
}

I want my first pane two pane layout first between homescreen and saved screen the other pane in recommendation and detail screen.

Would you want the two panes to be dependent on the available screen size as recommended by the Material 3 Guidelines for Canonical Layouts? Jetpack Compose has experimental support for that with the ListDetailPaneScaffold, including built-in navigation.
